# How to stop spotify from importing local files?

Tags: spotify

How do I stop spotify from importing local files?

Comment: -1 This question is easily answered by reading Spotify's guide on [Local Files](http://www.spotify.com/us/help/guides/local-files/). See the section titled "**Import**".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Edit --> preferences and unselect the following options.
[image]